# How to change the standard width of a page

Tags: themes, css

How can I expand the standard width of a page in a premium theme? It seems to be fixed to 800px, and I don't know where to start.

Comment: This really would depend on the theme - and also might be very involved, as changing the overall width would undoubtedly have knock-on effects elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2024, this operation is relatively easy to achieve, but it can be difficult to find where to edit the parameter.

- Go to `Appearance` -> `Editor` from the main administration panel
- Click on `Styles`
- Click on the pencil *"Edit styles"* icon
- It opens a column on the right, click on `Layout`

[image]

From here, you got a `Dimensions` section, where you can edit the width of the main content area through two global values:

- `Content`
- `Wide`

From the question asked here, @fuxia wanted to set the `Content`

Comment: I can't believe how Wordpress made difficult to find this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin panel -> Layout -> Editor and find and replace all "800px" with whatever width you want. (press CTRL+F to open search in your web browser)

Comment: If he/she doesn't know where to start, this suggestion is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Well, at least it's an answer...